# load custom icon per point with geojson in google maps apiv3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been using google maps for awhile now and have run into limitations with the kml layer(no mouseover only click)

so I thought I would tryout the data layer(geojson)

I cannot seem to figure out how to change the icons(marker image).

I am able to change all the markers to a specific image but I would like to be able to use one of 8 different images depending on the feature.property.generated from my db

```
 map.data.loadGeoJson('http://www.example.com/geojson.php?city_id=017');
     // Set mouseover event for each feature.
      map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        $('.map-tooltip').text(event.feature.getProperty('name'));
      });
```

my JSON FILE

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.1405,
               33.551667
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_0.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"017001",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"North"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.123269,
               33.552172
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_90.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"050010",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"East"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.122675,
               33.55155
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_60.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"050011",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"South"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.120978,
               33.551613
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_30.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"050012",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"West"
         }
      },
         {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.118667,
               33.6055
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_walk_18.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"017069",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"SE"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.118667,
               33.6055
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_111.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"017069",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"SW"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.11,
               33.5835
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_81.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"017070",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"NW"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.11,
               33.5835
            ]
         },
         "icon":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_42.png",
         "properties":{
            "name":"017070",
            "heading":null,
            "face":"NE"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

so I am not sure how to get the icon files to work
TIA for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the `icon` property in your geoJson (at least using the dataLayer methods) you need to move it into the "properties" object.  Then you can do this (like [this example of dynamic styles in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic))

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var icon=null;
  if (feature.getProperty('icon')) {
    icon = feature.getProperty('icon');
  }
  return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
    icon: icon
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dcs814q/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function(e) {
    // auto center map on markers
    if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
      bounds.extend(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // Set the icon from the "icon" property in the geoJson
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var icon = null;
    if (feature.getProperty('icon')) {
      icon = feature.getProperty('icon');
    }
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ ({
      icon: icon
    });
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

// modified geoJson
var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.1405,
        33.551667
      ]
    },

    "properties": {
      "name": "017001",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "North",
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_0.png"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.123269,
        33.552172
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "050010",
      "heading": null,
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_90.png",
      "face": "East"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.122675,
        33.55155
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_60.png",
      "name": "050011",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "South"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.120978,
        33.551613
      ]
    },

    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_30.png",
      "name": "050012",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "West"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.118667,
        33.6055
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_walk_18.png",
      "name": "017069",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "SE"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.118667,
        33.6055
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_111.png",
      "name": "017069",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "SW"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.11,
        33.5835
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_81.png",
      "name": "017070",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "NW"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-117.11,
        33.5835
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_42.png",
      "name": "017070",
      "heading": null,
      "face": "NE"
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```